# Tuple typescript as map returning type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I try to add tuple in the return of map but got error,

```
"use strict"

const row = ['true', '12', 'apple']

type cleanRowType =  [boolean, number, string]


const cleanRow: cleanRowType = row.map(
  (item, i) => i === 2 ? item : i === 1 ? +item : i === 0 ? Boolean(item) : '')


console.log('cleanRow', cleanRow)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-6dbd8k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript isn't smart enough to know the individual types of each element of the array, it only knows that each element is `boolean | number | string`. To fix this, don't use a map:

```js
const cleanRow: cleanRowType = [Boolean(row[0]), +row[1], row[2]];
```